# How can I hide dynamic id data on url when routing the another component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

When the component is routed,the id data is presented.But when the page reload,this does not show the normal design.How can I solve this problem ?Please, give me advice.Thanks.

```
<div className="pull-right">
    <Link to={`/detail/${total.id}`}>Detail</Link>
</div>
const App = () => (
    <app>
        <switch>
            <Route path='/detail/:id' component={Detail} />
        </switch>
    </app>
);
```

Comment: I think it's because of your server URL rewrite. what is your dev-server? webpack-dev-server or  ...?